# Referencing the SupportFragmentManager in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, xamarin, supportmapfragment

I am coding a Google Maps application in Xamarin and have successfully extended the class to use `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity`.

I am now wanting to change the `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity` to be a `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` so that I can have a `ViewPager` that has a Google Map fragment.

As I have now changed the class to extend from `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`, I cannot reference the `SupportFragmentManager`.

Here is my code:

```
private void InitMapFragment()
{
    _mapFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("map") as SupportMapFragment;
    if (_mapFragment == null)
    {
        GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
            .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
            .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(true)
            .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);

        FragmentTransaction fragTx = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        _mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
        fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.map, _mapFragment, "map");
        fragTx.Commit();
    }
}
```

How do I reference the `SupportFragmentManager` in a `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a Fragment you can get the fragment Manager with `getFragmentManager()` or `getChildFragmentManager()` if you have nested fragments, But you still need your Activity to extend FragmentActivity, you can have the viewpager within it. Or you can have something like this:

[image]

so you can later replace the MainFragment with some other Fragment.

Comment: How do I call the SupportFragmentManager, not the FragmentManager?

Comment: from a Fragment you can all getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

may be your MainActivity class is inheriting from ComponentActivity, then change it to AppCompatActivity
as supportFragmentManager is supported by AppCompatActivity class.
this won't make considerabale damage to your previous code

If in case app crashes use FragmentActivity instead of AppComatActivity to inherit from